# $0.333333$ - a recurring or non-terminating decimal?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I have read like,

1.All terminating and recurring decimals are RATIONAL NUMBERS.

2.All non-terminating and non recurring decimals are IRRATIONAL NUMBERS.

if the statements are right, then here comes my doubt.

$1/3=0.333333$ 
Here $3$ is recurring , so from statement 1) $0.3333$ or $1/3$ is a rational number.

And also $0.3333$ is non-terminating as the decimal is not ending or the remainder for 1/3 is not zero.
So from 2) $0.333$ is an irrational and it is non terminating.

So please clarify what is $0.3333$ - a recurring or non terminating?

Update: I got the answer from Mohokhbh -

0.3333 is both recurring and non terminating - it's a rational number .

My observation

---

Rational number = Terminating or recurring (anyone should suffice)

Irrational number = Non-terminating + Non-recurring(both should satisfy)

THANKS ALL, we can stop messaging this thread

Comment: It is both.  it "recurs" in that it is just a repetition of a pattern, just "3" in this case.  It is "non-terminating" because it doesn't terminate.  You can ignore the "terminating" case if you agree that something like .5 ends in a recurring string of $0$'s,

Comment: As a sidnote: $0.333333$ is terminating (and equals $\frac{333333}{1000000}$ instead of $\frac13$). You mean $0.\overline 3$.

Comment: Well,the 2 statements I mentioned are from wikipedia..so if 0.3333 is both recurring and non terminating then it should be both a rational number(as it is recurring) and irrational(non-terminating) , can a number be both rational and irrational at the same time?

Comment: @Hagen - Terminating decimal is the number which end up with  zero as remainder..so here 1/3 is a fraction which ends up with a quotient 0.333 and the remainder never equals to Zero. So how it is a terminating number ? Please clarify if my definition for terminating decimal is wrong. appreciate your inputs.

Comment: @SudheerSree The decimal representation for $1/3$ is nonterminating and recurring. The decimal  $0.333333$ is terminating - it has only six digits after the decimal point.

Comment: you can represent decimal expansion of all rational number with a infinite geometric series but can't do that with irrational numbers.

Answer (score 3):

1) A terminating decimal representation means a number can be represented by a finite string of digits in base $10$ notation, e.g. $0.5$, $0.25$, $0.8$, $2.4$

2) A non-terminating decimal representation means that your number will have an infinite number of digits to the right of the decimal point. There are two sorts of non-terminating decimal numbers.

2a) The first sort are called recurring non-terminating decimals. The decimal representations of these numbers consist of an infinite number of periodic repeats of a fixed string of digits to the right of the decimal point. Note that the repeating string can be composed of any number of digits - in the case of $\frac 13 = 0.333... = 0.\overline{3}$, the periodic string is just one digit long. But you can also have a number like $\frac 17 = 0.142857142857... = 0.\overline{142857}$. And in fact, to the immediate right of the decimal point, you can start with a finite string of non-repeating digits *before* the number goes into its periodic repeats, e.g. $3.1230980709807... = 3.123\overline{09807}$.

2b) The second sort are called non-recurring non-terminating decimals. The number cannot be represented as a repeat of any finite fixed string of digits. Put another way, the decimal representation is *aperiodic* (i.e. lacking a period). You will see numbers like $\sqrt 2 = 1.4142135623730950488016887242097...$ and $\pi = 3.14159265358979...$ in this category and these numbers appear to have "random" digits (no obvious pattern) to the right of the decimal point. However, and this is a fairly subtle point - the only requirement for this sort of decimal is aperiodicity, *not* randomness. An example of a clearly non-random non-recurring non-terminating decimal representation is this number: $0.123456789101112131415161718192021...$, which is a famous number known as *Champernowne's constant* and which is formed by concatenating the digits of the natural numbers in sequence.

And finally, you should note that Types 1 and 2a) are always *rational* whereas Type 2b) is always *irrational*.

Answer (score 0):

Your second point says that ".All non-terminating and non recurring decimals are IRRATIONAL NUMBERS." And $0.3333\dots$ is *recurring*, so it doesn't fit the second point. A recurring and non-terminating decimal is rational.
So

- recurring (terminal or not) means rational,
- non-recurring (and non terminating) means irrational.

Comment: ,thanks ,, you understood my question well :-) yes 0.333 is recurring and also a non-terminating,, So example for rational number should be like as you said:A recurring and non-terminating decimal is rational, but that's not the case, the two statements which I mentioned are right and taken from most of the websites..so I just want to be clarified with the example 0.3333 - as it is both recurring and non terminating.. how the above two statements are correct...

Comment: @SudheerSree: I am not sure that I understand. Let me update my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The first point you have stated should actually be all terminating *or* recurring decimals are rational numbers. Hence $0.33333...$ is actually a rational number.

**Definition of Rationality**: A number that can be represented in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers ($q$ not equal to zero) is a rational number.

$0.3333...=\frac{1}{3}$; hence it is a rational number.

Comment: @Lila , agreed with the comment that 0.333 is recurring. So it is rational. And it is also non- terminating as 1/3 never ends up with remainder Zero. As 1/3=0.333 is also a non terminating.. then it should be irrational right as per the saying like all non-terminating are irrational numbers..?

Comment: @Sudheer : not all non-terminating decimals are irrational. Only non-terminating and non-recurring decimals are irrational.

Comment: @Mohakbh- thanks..so Rational number = terminating or recurring(either one should suffice)                     irratinal number = non terminating + non recurring(both should satisfy)                           , is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Sudheer: exactly

Answer (score 0):

The second point menas *"All numbers that ar both non-terminating and non-recurring ..."* not *"All non-terminating numbers as well as all non-recurring numbers ..."*

Answer (score 0):

It is a recurring number, you have some digits that repeat themselves with a fixed period (in this case is just one digit, 3, and the period is then one).

The problem that you have is that you're not considering the second part of the definition of irrational numbers that you give, to be a non recurring decimal, so both definitions are mutually exclusive.

For instance, $\pi$ is an irrational number because, no matter how many decimals you take, there are no periodicity in those digits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face stems from an imprecision of the language that makes the situation quite confusing when described as you do.

The first sentence "All terminating and recurring decimals are RATIONAL NUMBERS." is supposed to say that all terminating decimals are rational and in addition all recurring decimals are rational. Put differently and as mentioned in another answer if a number is terminating *or* recurring then it is rational.

By contrast the second sentence "All non-terminating and non recurring decimals are IRRATIONAL NUMBERS." is supposed to say that a number that is (both) non-terminating and non-recurring is irrational.

I think the first sentence is just not phrased well it ought to read at least "All terminating and all recurring decimals are RATIONAL NUMBERS."

Comment: Thanks for sentence correction.. yes first statement can be read as All terminating and all recurring decimals are RATIONAL..as 0.3333 is both recurring and non terminating , is it a rational or irrational number

Comment: If a number is recurring it is automatically non-terminating, so "recurring and non terminating" is redundant and the same as "recurring" so that it is rational.

Answer (score -1):

It is recurring non-terminating number.